# Why this error? "No such property: Entry for class: java.util.Map"

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm following an example from [JENKINS-44085](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44085?focusedCommentId=346951&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-346951) issue very-bottom comments about creating a stage map almost to the T, but when I execute my code I get

```
No such property: Entry for class: java.util.Map
```

Here's my code. Variable 'pipeline' is defined somewhere else, and is valid.

```
def generateStage(String job, String targetVersion,
                  String rootVersion, Integer sleepTime=0) {
    return {
        stage("Deploying: ${job}") {
              sleep sleepTime
              pipeline.executeDeploymentPipeline(job,
                                                 targetVersion,
                                                 rootVersion)
        }
    }
}

def deployProcs(targetVersion, rootVersion) {
    int sleepTime = 0
    def procs = ["proc-proc", "proc-proc-high"]
    def parallelStagesMap = procs.collectEntries {
        ["${it}" : generateStage(it, targetVersion, rootVersion, sleepTime)]
        sleepTime += 5
    }
    parallel parallelStagesMap
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: Please create a [mcve], including code, full stack trace and other useful information that helps to replicate this issue.

Comment: Can you share your code?  This is because you are calling something like `yourMap.Entry` but without seeing your code it's hard to say exactly where.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike what @Christian pointed out, this is still a bug as of `1.176.1` with all plugins up to date. The workaround is to convert the map entries into a `[key, value]` *list* pair. To demonstrate, here is a simple code that can reproduce the OP's error:

```
['1':1].findAll { it.value > 0 }.collectEntries { it }
```

Here is the one with the workaround,

```
['1':1].collect { [it.key, it.value] }.findAll { it[1] > 0 }.collectEntries { it }
```

Note that `.collectEntries()` works with `list` pairs just fine, so no need to convert it back to any other form.

Answer (score 3):

It seems this is a [bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28276) in Jenkins pipelines. A [related one](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481) was fixed after version 2.158. So upgrading Jenkins should resolve this.

Comment: Please note, this issue still occurs as of 2.176.1 with all plugins up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but I did this as a workaround, for the calling function.

```
def deployProcs(targetVersion, rootVersion) {
    int sleepTime = 0
    def procs = ["proc-proc", "proc-proc-high"]
    Map parallelStagesMap = new TreeMap()
    procs.each {
        parallelStagesMap.put[it, generateStage(it, targetVersion, rootVersion, sleepTime))
        sleepTime += 5
    }
    parallel parallelStagesMap
}
```

Still bothers me why the original code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution proposed by @haridsv also works if you want to modify the map based on some conditions and return this modified map:

```
def b = [a: 'buba', b: 'cuba', c: 'cuda']

def s = true

def c = b
   .collect { s ? [it.key, it.value -= 'c'] : it }
   .collectEntries { it }

println c
```